# pkg-config --cflags opencv: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, pkg-config

I'm writing a basic example of opencv, but **make** command give me message

> g++-4.7.real: error: pkg-config --cflags opencv: No such file or directory
>
> g++-4.7.real: error: pkg-config --libs opencv: No such file or directory

issue command **pkg-config --cflag opencv** give me result as:

> -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include

and **pkg-config --libs opencv** give me:

> -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
> vudao@vudaopc:~/work/nmath/ntrainer$ pkg-config --libs opencv
> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a /usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libIlmImf.a /usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a /usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/liblibtiff.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so -lswscale -lavformat -lavutil -lz -lSDL -lasound -lavcodec -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl -lstdc++

Below is my Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-O2 -g 'pkg-config --cflags opencv'
LDFLAGS='pkg-config --libs opencv'

BIN=ntrainer

ntrainer : ntrainer.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN) ntrainer.cpp
```

My system is Ubuntu 12.10. I have installed opencv-2.4.7 successfully (I think) following instructions here http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/installing-opencv-2-2-in-ubuntu-11-04/

I also have configured and exported PKG_CONFIG_PATH into /etc/bash.bashrc, I'v also ran **ldconfig**

Please someone tell me what I'm missing? And how to correct it.
Thanks too much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You used incorrect quotes. You should use ` instead of ':

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-O2 -g `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Comment: If I built openCV in a local directory, what shall I change `pkg-config --cflags opencv` to?

Comment: Only CMake can work with local build. Pkg-config is created only for installation.

Comment: LDFLAGS=`pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs` for opencv4

Answer (score 1):

For me, the file was there but the path was wrong:

I had to look for the `opencv.pc` file, make sure it is in the path for the pkgconfig program to find (i.e. in one of the pkgconfig folders) and then make sure the `prefix` path in there is right.

In my case it was wrong because it was not installed via `make install` but i made a `make package` package because it was cross-compiled, and the path I had installed it at didn't match the CMAKE path.

running

`pkg-config --cflags opencv`

or

`pkg-config --libs opencv`

tells you where it is looking for the files, so you can make sure they match.